# I want to find out the employee who is working for past 3 years

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a data like this:

```
7369~SMITH~CLERK~7902~19801217~800~~20~
7499~ALLEN~SALESMAN~7698~19810220~1600~300~30~
7521~WARD~SALESMAN~7698~19810222~1250~500~30~
7566~JONES~MANAGER~7839~19810402~2975~~20~
7654~MARTIN~SALESMAN~7698~19810928~1250~1400~30~
7698~BLAKE~MANAGER~7839~19810501~2850~~30~
7782~CLARK~MANAGER~7839~19810609~2450~~10~
7788~SCOTT~ANALYST~7566~19821209~3000~~20~
7839~KING~PRESIDENT~~19811117~5000~~10~
7844~TURNER~SALESMAN~7698~19810908~1500~0~30~
```

In the entry 5th filed is date of joining. Now i want to extract the year from the 5th field ?

Comment: What have you tried? Also, you know it's 2019 now, right?

Comment: A far more interesting question would be the provenance of that table.  It's not really a Unix & Linux question, though.  Ironically, knowing its history as a PL/SQL example for _at least_ 28 years shows that `awk` is not the best tool for querying it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to compose awk command with date comparison. Try one of these - based on your date(1):

- BSD date

  ```
  awk -F'~' '$5 <= '$(date -v-3y +%Y%m%d)'{print $2,$3}' file
  ```
- GNU (Linux) date

  ```
  awk -F'~' '$5 <= '$(date -d '3 years ago' +%Y%m%d)'{print $2,$3}' file
  ```

Comment: You might want to consider the `-v` option: `awk -F'~' -v date="$(date -d ...)"  '$5 <= date ...'` -- that makes quoting easier.

Comment: Thanks that's even better. Feel free to update the answer. @glennjackman

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the file containing your data is called input:

`cut -d '~' -f 5 input | cut -c 1-4`

Output:

```
1980
1981
1981
1981
1981
1981
1981
1982
1981
1981
```

Comment: thanks for the solution but i need beyond the extraction of the year from the field, i need comparison of the year with the current year.

Comment: Put that in the question next time, not in the title.